# Unable to generate script

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am having one azure sql database.

When I try to genearate database script by selecting "Schema and data" or "data only" option, sql server is throwing error: **can not generate script.**

When I select schema only, then it successfully generates script.

is this related to some permission?

Comment: which task and tool did you use?

Comment: Sql server management studio v17.4

Answer (score 0):

I just did mine and it worked perfectly. Check if you can find the error message - the answer lies there. And yes, I think the most likely cause is permissions. Also, check circular references - I had that issue in the past.

I used SSMS from my local machine.